# How to add a button to gridview controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have record from sql database printing into gridview.  I want to make another column that will add a button that I can link to in the Code Behind.  When I use asp:ButtonField I cant find a way to link it to a function... Also how can i associate it with the id that is being printed? So if I wanted the button to delete the record, how can I make it so it knows its id number 10 so it will pass that id to the Code Behind so I can delete the appropriate record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must need this, I think

```
 <asp:TemplateField>
      <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnDelete" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Printedid") %>' CommandName="Delete"  />
      </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
```

and then you can get in code behind of that particular id

```
protected void grd_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
    {
       e.CommandArgument // will return the Rrinted id 
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The button field will call the RowCommand event passing in the command name and command argument that you specify in the field.